# R - merge lists with overwrite and recursion

Tags: r, list, recursion

Suppose I have two lists with names,

```
a = list( a=1, b=2, c=list( d=1, e=2 ), d=list( a=1, b=2 ) )
b = list( a=2, c=list( e=1, f=2 ), d=3, e=2 )
```

I'd like to recursively merge those lists, overwriting entries if the second argument contains conflicting values. I.e. the expected output would be

```
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 2

$c
$c$d
[1] 1

$c$e
[1] 1

$c$f
[1] 2

$d
[1] 3

$e
[1] 2
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not so sure if a custom function is necessary here. There is a function `utils::modifyList()` to perform this exact same operation! See [modifyList](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/modifyList.html) for more info.

```
a <- list( a=1, b=2, c=list( d=1, e=2 ), d=list( a=1, b=2 ) )
b <- list( a=2, c=list( e=1, f=2 ), d=3, e=2 )

modifyList(a, b) # updates(modifies) 'a' with 'b'
```

Which gives the following

```
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 2

$c
$c$d
[1] 1

$c$e
[1] 1

$c$f
[1] 2

$d
[1] 3

$e
[1] 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't considered the correct answer

Comment: @rmg I suppose `modifyList` was fairly new in December 2012 and thus little known ... and I haven't looked at this question in 6 years.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez thanks for the response- I've used this a bunch

Answer (score 9):

I think you'll have to write your own recursive function here.

A function that takes in two lists, `list1` and `list2`. 
If:

- `list1[[name]]` exists but not `list2[[name]]`, use `list1[[name]]`;
- `list1[[name]]` exists as well as `list2[[name]]` and both are not lists, use `list2[[name]]`;
- otherwise, recurse with `list1[[name]]` and `list2[[name]]` as the new lists.

Something like:

```
myMerge <- function (list1, list2) {
    allNames <- unique(c(names(list1), names(list2)))
    merged <- list1 # we will copy over/replace values from list2 as necessary
    for (x in allNames) {
        # convenience
        a <- list1[[x]]
        b <- list2[[x]]
        if (is.null(a)) {
            # only exists in list2, copy over
            merged[[x]] <- b
        } else if (is.list(a) && is.list(b)) {
            # recurse
            merged[[x]] <- myMerge(a, b)
        } else if (!is.null(b)) {
            # replace the list1 value with the list2 value (if it exists)
            merged[[x]] <- b
        }
    }
    return(merged)
}
```

Caveats - if your lists to be merged are weird, you might get weird output. For example:

```
a <- list( a=list(a=1, b=2), b=3 )
b <- list( a=2 )
```

Then your merged list has `a=2, b=3`. This is because the value from `b$a` overrides the value from `a$a`, even though `a$a` is a list (you did not specify what would happen if this were the case). However it is simple enough to modify `myMerge` to handle these sorts of cases. Just remember - use `is.list` to test if it's a list, and `is.null(myList$a)` to see if entry `a` exists in list `myList`.

---

Here is the "vectorized" version using `sapply`:

```
merge.lists <- function(a, b) {
    a.names <- names(a)
    b.names <- names(b)
    m.names <- sort(unique(c(a.names, b.names)))
    sapply(m.names, function(i) {
        if (is.list(a[[i]]) & is.list(b[[i]])) merge.lists(a[[i]], b[[i]])
        else if (i %in% b.names) b[[i]]
        else a[[i]]
    }, simplify = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I am unsure if this can be vectorised using `vapply`/similar while still keeping the nested structure.

Comment: That's great! Exactly what I need. BTW, my example had the 'weird' list entry (`d` in both lists).

Comment: If you add `if(!is.null(a) && !is.null(b) && xor(is.list(a), is.list(b))){
      merged[[x]] <- c(a,b)
    }`

at the beginning of that if statement, you can account for that edge case, admittedly losing the overwrite.